# Fallout 1 on OSX Yosemite help

Tags: technical-issues, macos, wine, fallout

I have tried a Wine wrapper I downloaded, but it's probably out of date because when I try to run the game I get a black or white screen. I'm on OS X Yosemite. If anyone has the GOG version that was cancelled a while ago, or has a way I can get it going, I would really love it. I have latest version of Wine and the Windows Fallout game (GOG install version). Thanks for any help. Here's the wrapper I downloaded: http://portingteam.com/files/file/7252-fallout-1

Comment: If you got your license on GOG I believe they still support it. If they aren't providing you with links open a support ticket with them and they may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to run Fallout in Wine on OSX (10.11, El Capitan) either. And as stated in the [Wine wiki entry for Fallout 1](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=43), the game is not working on Mac.

You may try to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), setup an Ubuntu 14.04 (both are free) and try the app in there. If it's not working you have to get a Windows license and setup a Windows virtual machine with VirtualBox.